# Не могу зайти на сайт flutter.dev

Tags: flutter

Пытаюсь зайти на flutter.dev через ноут(MacOs Catalina 10.15.5) через Google Chrome. Попробовал как [показали тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55375467/cant-access-flutter-dev-mac-os), но. увы у меня нет папки resolver в /etc.

Вот тут список файлов в /etc
[image: Вот тут список файлов в /etc]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте зайти на flutter.io , это тот же сайт.
Попробуйте браузер Opera с включённым встроенным vpn.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я уж. flutter.io перенаправляет на flutter.dev. А другие браузеры тоже использовал(Opera, Safari, Mozilla)